# Failed to open stream error when trying to use mysqldump and exec for db backups

Tags: php, exec, mysql

With the following code I get *Warning: file(filename.sql.gz) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory*. What am I doing wrong?

```
$command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser -h localhost --password=$dbpwd $dbname | gzip > $filename";
exec($command);

if ($sendEmail)
{
$attachmentname = basename($filename);

$message = "Compressed database backup file $attachmentname attached.";
$mime_boundary = "<<<:" . md5(time());
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode(implode("", file($filename))));

$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";

$content = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$content.= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$content.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$content.= $message."\r\n";
$content.= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$content.= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$content.= "Content-Type: Application/Octet-Stream; name=\"$attachmentname\"\r\n";
$content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$content.= $data."\r\n";
$content.= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
}

if (!$keepFile) unlink($filename);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have write permission to the directory where you're trying to create `$filename`.

Comment: Unrelated issue, but you probably shouldn't use `file()` with a compressed file, it's for reading text files. Use `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: You probably want to use a third-party mailing tool like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.  Assembling your own MIME headers is insanity.

Comment: @Barmar if I make the directory writeable, the CMS that powers the site throws a 404, switch it back to 755 and I get the error above again.

Comment: Then you need to write to some other directory, like /tmp.